# connecting to remote webservice using SOAP and WSDL using flex or actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

The requirement is to get the method named getIncidentList() from web service using Soap and wsdl using Flex or Actionscript.
Can anyone help me i have a code which is not working:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:WebService id="DirectoryService"
         wsdl="http://cmuicds.rutgers.edu/uicds/core/ws/services/DirectoryService.wsdl" 
         useProxy="false"   
         showBusyCursor="true"
         result="onResult(event)" 
         fault="onFault(event)">    
      </mx:WebService>

      <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
      <mx:Button id="button"
            label="get incidents from web service"
            click="button_click()"/>
      <mx:ComboBox id="cmb" dataProvider="{zipfls}" labelField="name" width="241" height="24"/>
      </mx:ApplicationControlBar>


      <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable] private var zipfls:ArrayCollection;
            private var flag:Boolean;

        private function button_click():void 
        {
            //Alert.show("Hi");
            //DirectoryService.GetIncidentList.send();
            DirectoryService.GetIncidentList();
            flag = DirectoryService.canLoadWSDL();
            //flag = DirectoryService.hasOwnProperty();
            //Alert.show("Testing....." + flag);
            //Alert.show("Description " +DirectoryService.operations);

            } 

             private function onResult(evt:ResultEvent):void 
            {
            zipfls = new ArrayCollection();                 
            //textArea.text = ObjectUtil.toString(evt.result);
            zipfls = evt.result as ArrayCollection;
            Alert.show("Is data comming in?" + zipfls.length);
            }

            private function onFault(evt:FaultEvent):void 
            {
            Alert.show(evt.type);

            }


           ]]>
        </mx:Script>

 </mx:Application>
```

Comment: Your code look good. Can you check that your webservice have crossdomain? you can sniff your request with Charles Proxy.

Comment: They are not maintaining cross domain policy file on the  web server

Comment: They have to or you can not access the data from wsdl

Comment: @Papachan--->could you plz explain your ans in detail?..I do not know whether web service has crossdomain policy file or not. When i run this code i get a authentication window asking for username and password.after entering it it dose not do anything. Actually it should show the output in text area, but it doesn't. I really need help oon this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling method properly

and event **button_click** should be

```
    private function button_click():void 
    {
        DirectoryService.GetIncidentList();

    }
```

i.e. **send** should not be used.

also see [Using WebService components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: yes i removed it...i m not using it anymore. but still can not call that particular method.If i Alert.show("Description " +DirectoryService.operations); i get[Object Object] that mean i m able to connect to webservice and can call operations.

Comment: Are you getting any error on console, either on client/Flex or server/Service?

Comment: Are you getting any popup on client in Flex? use "evt.fault.faultString" instead of "evt.type" in fault handler

Comment: i am getting onfault function and  word Fault as a result after 10 -15 min

Comment: it says it needs a parameter GetIncidentListRequest

Comment: Whats signature of function/operation "GetIncidentListRequest" in web service, i think you are not passing required parameter, when calling this function/operation

Comment: <wsdl:operation name="GetIncidentList"> <wsdl:input message="tns:GetIncidentListRequest" name="GetIncidentListRequest"> </wsdl:input> <wsdl:output message="tns:GetIncidentListResponse" name="GetIncidentListResponse"> </wsdl:output> </wsdl:operation> AND the tns is http://uicds.org/DirectoryService

Comment: so i need to pass 2 parameters.but i am not sure how to pass those parameters. Should it be like this?  ws.GetIncidentList.send(["http://uicds.org/DirectoryService", "GetIncidentListRequest"]);

Comment: Since its a RPC type call, so call it like native method

Comment: FOR WSDL_SIGNATURE <wsdl:operation name="insertRecord" parameterOrder="username emailaddress"> METHOD_CALL should be "userRequest.insertRecord(username.text, emailaddress.text);" Please see link from answer.

Comment: @KANCHANCHAUDHARI let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2645/discussion-between-imran-and-kanchan-chaudhari)